# Changing an existing datagridview column

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

I want to change a datagridview column 'TeamAssignment' which loads from the database to have dropdowns (which is also populated from the database)

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(My.Resources.FCLRptConn)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("spFCLLUVTeamAssignment", conn)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim TeamAssign As New DataSet

        da.Fill(TeamAssign)

        teamComBo.HeaderText = "Team Assignment"
        teamComBo.DataPropertyName = "TeamAssignment"
        teamComBo.DataSource = TeamAssign.Tables(0)
        teamComBo.DisplayMember = "FCLTeamName"
        teamComBo.ValueMember = "FCLTeamID"

        dgvAgentAssignment.Columns.RemoveAt(5)
        dgvAgentAssignment.Columns.Insert(5, teamComBo)
```

This is what I have used but I get an error that says that a column exists. How would I keep my existing column without having to remove it but populate it with the dropdowns?
Thanks

Comment: DGV column types cannot be changed.  You can remove and delete one; and create a new one of a different type and add it.

Comment: So even if it is loaded/ binded from the database I still have to remove it but save the dropdown selection back to the database with the deleted column?

Comment: Use predefined columns. Create two columns one with combobox(`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`) and one without. Then use column `.Visible` property to show/hide what you want